# Returning multiple lines from an SQLite database value

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I wish to return the data from an SQLite database value to an HTML template **formatted to display across multiple lines**. My database table is called 'Coat' and was created from an SQLAlchemy model.

```
class Coat(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=True)
    price = db.Column(db.Float)
    image1 = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=True, default='default.jpg')
    image2 = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=True)
```

The column I am trying to return/format correctly is 'description'. I entered the values into this database using DB Browser for SQLite, where the 'description' values are shown as multiple lines.

[image]

Here is the route that renders the product_coat template

```
@app.route('/product_coat/<id>')
def product_coat(id):
product = Coat.query.get(id)
return render_template('product_coat.html', title='Product', product=product)
```

Finally, here is product_coat.html

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}

    <div class="left">
        <img class="product_image" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/coats/' + product.image2) }}">
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <p class="description">{{ product.description }}</p>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Currently my code is returning the 'description' as one continuous line, eg 'Classic fit Harrington style Zip fastening Front pockets Borg collar 100% Cotton Machine washable Colour: Khaki Product Code: 64J18UKHA'.

What I am trying to do is to have this displayed on multiple lines eg

Classic fit 
Harrington style 
Zip fastening 
Front pockets 
Borg collar 
100% Cotton 
Machine washable 
Colour: Khaki 
Product Code: 64J18UKHA

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Maybe create an html table or a list ('ul') for this?

Comment: or perhaps just wrap the text in `<pre> … </pre>`

Comment: The <pre> tag does exactly what I am looking to do, thankyou very much